# Making Tile Service fast in ArcGIS Server for Silverlight Viewer?

Tags: arcgis-server, performance, tile-server, arcgis-silverlight-viewer

I am publishing a tile service in ArcGIS Server but when I call it in ArcGIS Silverlight Viewer it took a lot of time to open completely, and panning is very slow.

What should I do to make my app smooth and fast?

Comment: It could be that there's too many layers to render on the fly and you may need to implement some sort of caching mechanism.

Comment: so far i m viewing few layers, can you pls guide me about a best cache settings?